# Codeigniter Dompdf can't remove the black footer.

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, dompdf

I am using dompdf in codeigniter, the HTML page looks fine but in dompdf generated pdf, there is a black box.

[image]

The code in the footer section is:

```
    <div class="signature-footer">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;border-style:dashed; border-top:1px black;border-bottom:1px solid white; border-left:1px solid white; border-right:1px solid white;">Prepared By<br><?php echo $quotation_detail[0]->employee_name; ?><br><?php echo $quotation_detail[0]->designation_name ; ?></td>
            <td style="width: 30%;border-top:1px solid white;border-bottom:1px solid white; border-left:1px solid white; border-right:1px solid white;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;border-top:1px solid white;border-bottom:1px solid white; border-left:1px solid white; border-right:1px solid white;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 30%;border-top:1px solid white;border-bottom:1px solid white; border-left:1px solid white; border-right:1px solid white;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;border-style:dashed; border-top:1px black;border-bottom:1px solid white; border-left:1px solid white; border-right:1px solid white;">Authorized Signature<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div><div class="below-border-footer"></div><div style="text-align: center"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>interface/img/footerImage.png"> </div></div></body>
    </html>
```

CSS for these two elements:

```
.below-border-footer {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 0 ;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.signature-footer {

    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative; 
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

I've tried for hours but no result. How can I remove the black box in the footer?

Comment: Which version of dompdf are you using?

Comment: Can you post the full code of your  HTML & CSS

Comment: dompdf version 0.5.1. and I am afraid i can't it's confidential. You can tell the parts to look for the black box. there are some elements with silver background but no element with black background.